# How to generate a random number for 2d array of a different type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

A 2d array of type color

```
enum color{black, white};
color A[nrow][ncol];
```

I need a random number generator so that [i][j] have either '0' or '1' then I would say :

```
if (A[i][j]==0)
  {
    A[i][j]=black;
  }
```

The things is, in main we write:

```
srand(unsigned int (NULL);
```

so when I write:

```
for (int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
  {
    A[i][j]= rand () % 2;
  }
```

An error says that int cannot be assigned to type color. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can cast the result of `1+ rand () % 12;` to `color`.

Comment: Your question and your code are very muddled. How many colours do you really have - 2 or 12 ?

Comment: `static_cast<color>(i)` It's up to you to ensure the input values correspond to an enum value. Be aware `srand` is a poor number generator.

Comment: What do you mean by cast?

Comment: It's a feature of the language, you can find tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to cast the int to color

```
 A[i][j]= (color)(rand () % 2);
```

Other option is

```
 A[i][j]= (rand () % 2) ? white : black;
```

BTW I would prefer:

```
 A[i][j]= (rand () & 1) ? white : black;
```

Comment: Prefer c++ cast (`static_cast`) over C-cast.